# Open CV VideoWriter creates empty file - no error thrown

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to convert frames stored in a folder into a video file. I'm using open cv2.VideoWriter() to do this, it doesn't throw any error but the files produced are empty. I was trying to change fourcc and frames per second but nothing works.
Would you have a look at teh code and suggest what may cause this issue?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
import re
import natsort 

def convert_frames_to_video(pathIn,pathOut,fps):
    frame_array = []
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn, f))]
    #for sorting the file names properly
    natsort.natsorted(files,reverse=True)
    #files.sort(key=lambda f: int(re.sub('\D', '', f)))
    for i in range(len(files)):
        filename=pathIn + files[i]
        #reading each files
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        height = 407
        width = 724
        layers = 3
        #height, width, layers = cv2.imread(img).shape
        size = (width,height)
        print(filename)
        #inserting the frames into an image array
        frame_array.append(img)
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,fourcc, fps, size)
    for i in range(len(frame_array)):
        # writing to a image array
        out.write(frame_array[i])
    out.release()
```

```
def main():
    pathIn= '/content/CarND-LaneLines-P1/White Right Detected'
    pathOut = '/content/CarND-LaneLines-P1/vid4.mp4'
    fps = 8.0
    convert_frames_to_video(pathIn, pathOut, fps)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Files stored in the folder are all `.jpg` format with names like: `frame1`, `frame2` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a forward slash `/` in the command `filename=pathIn + files[i]`, and ended up adding `None` to your `frame_array`, because [cv2.imread](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) doesn't return any error indication if the path or image does not exist:

> Even if the image path is wrong, it won't throw any error, but print img will give you `None`

```
In [135]: x = cv2.imread("NON_EXISTING_IMAGE")
In [136]: type(x)
Out[136]: NoneType
```

You also have to use the expected image size described in the `cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,fourcc, fps, size)` for all your images. If that is not the case for the frames in your folder, you would've to use `resize` as the example below:

> img = cv2.resize(img, size)

Im my test case I've used a different input image shape, so I apply the `resize` function to match your expected `height` and `width`:

```
/content
├── CarND-LaneLines-P1
│   ├── vid4.mp4
│   └── White Right Detected
│       ├── ezgif-frame-001.jpg  # (338, 600, 3)
│       ├── ezgif-frame-002.jpg  # (338, 600, 3)
│       ├── ezgif-frame-003.jpg  # (338, 600, 3)
|       ├── ...
|       ├── ...
```

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
import re
import natsort 

def convert_frames_to_video(pathIn,pathOut,fps):
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn, f))]
    #for sorting the file names properly
    natsort.natsorted(files,reverse=True)
    #files.sort(key=lambda f: int(re.sub('\D', '', f)))
    height = 407
    width = 724
    layers = 3
    #height, width, layers = cv2.imread(img).shape
    size = (width,height)    
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,fourcc, fps, size)
    for frame_file in files:
        # use join here as in your early list comprehension
        filename= join(pathIn, frame_file)
        #reading each files
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        #resize each file
        img = cv2.resize(img, size)
        out.write(img)
    out.release()

def main():
    pathIn= '/content/CarND-LaneLines-P1/White Right Detected'
    pathOut = '/content/CarND-LaneLines-P1/vid4.mp4'
    fps = 8.0
    convert_frames_to_video(pathIn, pathOut, fps)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

```
#ls -lah "/content/CarND-LaneLines-P1/vid4.mp4"
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4M May  9 14:42 /content/CarND-LaneLines-P1/vid4.mp4
```